Initialize environment modules in TaskProlog with Slurm
I have the following Slurm setup (with slurm version 24.05.0):

one server running slurmctld
one server running slurmdbd
one login node and
(currently) one compute node.

On the compute node, there are environment modules that can be loaded with module load .... However, the module command is only available after /etc/profile.d/modules.sh is sourced, which is the case after a normal SSH login, but not when a slurm job is executed.
Currently, for using module load, one has to write an sbatch script like:
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1

# Currently, this is necessary here ...
source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
# ... in order for this to work:
module load miniconda
# ...
# DO COMPUTATION
# 
# purging or unloading is not done automatically, so that currently temporary files remain if not called here...
module purge

My idea was to make a TaskProlog script that does the source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh and a TaskEpilog script that executes module purge. I tried a lot of different TaskProlog scripts, including using a . instead of source or using cat /etc/profile.d/modules.sh (because the Manual uses things like echo "export ..."), but none of these versions seemed to work.
Can someone give me a hint on how to get this work? I would really like to automate this, so users do not get too confused and all temporary files get deleted automatically etc.
Thank you very much in advance!
If it is relevant in this context: The normal users only "exist" on slurmctl and on the login node (in /etc/passwd), but are not available on the compute node (except the slurm and munge user and an admin user). This works fine ...
